# How to pass korean characters in URL

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Iam using simple_html_dom to extract data from other website. Arguments in korean language are passed to url like domain.com?q=한국어.

when i pass korean language arguments, it is throwing 400 error. but this url is working in wget but not in php.

below is the code iam using

```
include('../simple_html_dom.php');
$content = file('sample');
$string= $content[2];
$string = str_replace("\n", "", $string);
$string = str_replace("\r", "", $string);
$url='https://www.example.com/search?q='.$string;
$html=file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('#someids') as $e)
{
//do something
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apply proper URL encoding. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

Those are not regular characters. use `urlencode` to encode the url into a readable format as below;

```
$url='https://www.example.com/search?q='.urlencode($string);
```

OR

```
$string = urlencode($string);
$url= 'https://www.example.com/search?q='.$string;
$html=file_get_html($url);
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: getting error failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/sn/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php on line 82
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on bool in

Comment: Yes! Its totally my fault. you need to use `urlencode` only around the `$string` else the `://` after the `http` will also be encoded. I have fixed this in my answer.